# Animated webp frames get cropped by Safari (seen on iOS 14.7)

Tags: ios, safari, webp

We were really happy when we heard that Safari was finally able to display the much-needed download-time-saving webp image format. As of iOS 14.7 Safari seems to be fine with static webps. But when it comes to animated webps, it looks like Safari has a problem with those. Because not all but some frames in my animated webps get cropped horizontally with almost half of the image gone. It looks really terrible as it makes my app look glitchy.

Does anyone know a quick fix for that yet?

Note: All the other browsers are perfectly fine with my animated webps.

Note: No other image format can do what webps can; therefore using another format as a fallback is not an option.